# bottom up fibonacci in python using O(1) space

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I want to write a bottom up fibonacci using O(1) space. My problem is python's recursion stack is limiting me from testing large numbers. Could someone provide an alternate or optimization to what I have? This is my code:

```
def fib_in_place(n):
    def fibo(f2, f1, i):
        if i < 1:
            return f2
        else:
            return fibo(f1, f2+f1, i -1)
    return fibo(0, 1, n)
```

Comment: is writing it recursively a requirement?

Comment: Your code actually looks reasonable (bloated, but not the naive version with two recursive calls per call). How large of a number are we talking here? Are you running into the default recursion limit of 1000?

Comment: You're using O(n) stack space here. This would only be O(1) space if Python had tail call elimination. (Actually, it wouldn't be O(1) space anyway, because the assumption that integers take constant space breaks down almost immediately, but that problem is baked into the problem definition. You can't really fix that one.)

Comment: I would go for using a generator if you want O(1) space

Comment: @JakeBurkhead unless there is a way to write it in a bottom-up fashion without using recursion, then yes recursion is a requirement

Comment: The standard iterative solution fits your requirements, then.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no, 100

Comment: @user2357112 but that isn't bottom-up, iterative is top-down

Comment: @donutjuice: It's bottom-up.

Comment: I was under the impression that recalculating each fib(n) down to fib(0) is considered top-down.

Comment: `fib_in_place(100)` produces an immediate result of 354224848179261915075 on my machine. What happens on your machine?

Comment: @donutjuice just convert your recursive calls into the equivalent loop. most always there are equivalent recursive and iterative solutions to problems. they are two ways of doing things repeatedly

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's a limitation set in the assignment I'm working on. the set recursion limit is 100

Comment: If you're supposed to use recursion, and you can only have 100 recursive calls, and you want to find the 100th value... that's either perfectly fine or impossible, depending on off-by-one errors.

Comment: This is not O(1) space - it's O(N) - the stack is also taking up some space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can memoize the Fibonacci function for efficiency, but if you require a recursive function, it's still going to take at least O(n):

```
def mem_fib(n, _cache={}):
    '''efficiently memoized recursive function, returns a Fibonacci number'''
    if n in _cache:
        return _cache[n]
    elif n > 1:
        return _cache.setdefault(n, mem_fib(n-1) + mem_fib(n-2))
    return n
```

This is from my answer on the main Fibonacci in Python question: [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494594/541136)

If you're allowed to use iteration instead of recursion, you should do this:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:            # First iteration:
        yield a            # yield 0 to start with and then
        a, b = b, a + b    # a will now be 1, and b will also be 1, (0 + 1)
```

usage:

```
>>> list(zip(range(10), fib()))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 5), (6, 8), (7, 13), (8, 21), (9, 34)]
```

If you just want to get the nth number:

```
def get_fib(n):
    fib_gen = fib()
    for _ in range(n):
        next(fib_gen)
    return next(fib_gen)
```

and usage

```
>>> get_fib(10)
55
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this implementation, I want to write it in a bottom-up fashion but not accumulate my answers in a list. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Fun note: the iterative Fibonacci code is the first thing you see when you go to the [official Python home page](http://www.python.org).

Comment: When trying your generator version it returns "<generator object fib_in_place at 0x . . .>". Do I need an import or something?

Comment: That *is* fun. @donutjuice You're trading off space for time, whether you store the data in stack frames with recursion or whether you use a cache - only the cache is not as limited nor as expensive in space as a stack is. I don't really know what you mean by bottom-up. I'll demonstrate usage with another function.

Answer (score 7):

Using recursion this way means you're using O(N) space, not O(1) - the O(N) is in the stack.

Why use recursion at all?

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return a
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. Couldn't really think of an iterative version but this is similar to one of the other answers given. I wish I could give you both the  "accepted answer"!

Answer (score 3):

Why use iteration at all?

```
def fib(n):
    phi_1 = (math.sqrt(5) + 1) / 2
    phi_2 = (math.sqrt(5) - 1) / 2
    f = (phi_1**n - phi_2**n) / math.sqrt(5)
    return round(f)
```

The algebraic result is exact; the **round** operation is only to allow for digital representation inaccuracy.

Comment: Should actually be `f = (phi_1**n - phi_2**n) / math.sqrt(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Tail-recursive definitions are easily turned into iterative definitions.  If necessary, flip the condition so that the tail-recursive call is in the 'if' branch.

```
def fibo(f2, f1, i):
    if i > 0:
        return fibo(f1, f2+f1, i -1)
    else:
        return f2
```

Then turn 'if' into 'while', replace return  with unpacking assignment of the new arguments, and (optionally) drop 'else'.

```
def fibo(f2, f1, i):
    while i > 0:
        f2, f1, i = f1, f2+f1, i -1
    return f2
```

With iteration, you do not need the nested definition.

```
def fib_efficient(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('fib argument n cannot be negative')
    new, old = 0, 1
    while n:
        new, old = old, old+new
        n -= 1
    return new
```

Local names 'new' and 'old' refer to Fibonacci's use of biological reproduction to motivate the sequence.  However, the story works better with yeast cells instead of rabbits.  Old, mature yeast cells reproduce by budding off new, immature cells.  (The original source of the function in India appears to be Virahanka counting the number a ways to make a Sanskrit poetic line with n beats from an ordered sequence of 1- and 2-beat syllables.)