# What would be the best answer for this Fibonacci excercise in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

What's the best answer for this Fibonacci exercise in Python?

http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/language/functions.html#exercises

> Exercise: Fibonacci sequence
>
> Write a function that displays the n first terms of the Fibonacci
>   sequence, defined by:
>
> - u<sub>0</sub> = 1; u<sub>1</sub> = 1
> - u<sub>(n+2)</sub> = u<sub>(n+1)</sub> + u<sub>n</sub>

If this were simply asking a Fibonacci code, I would write like this:

```
def fibo_R(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return fibo_R(n-1) + fibo_R(n-2)
print(fibo_R(6))
```

... However, in this exercise, the initial conditions are both 1 and 1, and the calculation is going towards the positive direction (+). I don't know how to set the end condition. I've searched for an answer, but I couldn't find any. How would you answer this?

Comment: In the python main site have the solution https://www.python.org/

Comment: You wrote a function to get only the n'th element.  They asked for the first n, so you're going to repeat a lot of work computing each element when you could just be building on previous results.

Comment: One word: memoization.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948082/bottom-up-fibonacci-in-python-using-o1-space?rq=1 has some relevant discussion about different ways to define the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `u_(n+2) = u_(n+1) + u_n` is equivalent to `u_n = u_(n-1) + u_(n-2)`, i.e. your previous code will still apply. Fibonacci numbers are by definition defined in terms of their predecessors, no matter how you phrase the problem.

A good approach to solve this is to define a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which produces the elements of the Fibonacci sequence on demand:

```
def fibonacci():
    i = 1
    j = 1

    while True:
        yield i
        x = i + j
        i = j
        j = x
```

You can then take the [first N items of the generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234090/how-to-take-the-first-n-items-from-a-generator-or-list-in-python) via e.g. `itertools.islice`, or you use `enumerate` to keep track of how many numbers you saw:

```
for i, x in enumerate(fibonacci()):
  if i > n:
    break
  print x
```

Having a generator means that you can use the same code for solving many different problems (and quite efficiently though), such as:

- getting the n'th fibonacci number
- getting the first n fibonacci numbers
- getting all fibonacci numbers satisfying some predicate (e.g. all fibonacci numbers lower than 100)

Comment: I take your answer as the best answer because you mentioned "u_(n+2) = u_(n+1) + u_n is equivalent to u_n = u_(n-1) + u_(n-2)" and the initial condition are i=1, j=1. I was too much attached to recursion, but you made me aware of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to calculate a fibonacci sequence is by simply starting at the beginning and looping until you have calculated the n-th number. Recursion produces way too many method calls since you are calculating the same numbers over and over again.

This function calculates the first `n` fibonacci numbers, stores them in a list and then prints them out:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    array = [1]
    a = 1
    b = 1
    if n == 1:
        print array
    for i in range(n-1):
        fib = a + b
        a = b
        b = fib
        array.append(fib)
    print array
```

Comment: There is a way that is a formula, it uses O(1) memory and time. I guess the exsercise (i cant spell) meant the recursive way.

Comment: The task is to calculate the first n fibonacci numbers, not just the n-th number. Filling a list with n elements alone takes O(n)

Comment: @AmitGold There's nothing in the exercise description that mandates using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a super memory-efficient solution, use a generator that only produces the next number on demand:

```
def fib_generator():
  e1, e2 = 0, 1
  while True:
    e1,e2 = e2, e1+e2
    yield e1

f = fib_generator()
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
## dump the rest with a for-loop
for i in range(3, 50):
  print(next(f))
```

The recursive solution is the most elegant, but it is slow. Keiwan's loop is the fastest for a large number of elements.

Yes, definitely no globals as correctly observed by DSM. Thanks!

Comment: Why the use of globals?

Comment: A side note: using global variables will usually by slow; a class will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative recursive just to show that things can be done in slightly different ways:

```
def fib2(n): return n if n < 2 else fib2( n - 1 ) + fib2( n - 2 )
```